# How can I apply some calculations using multiple columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do calculate price per unit based on price and pack_count columns from a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
# assign data of lists.
data = {'price': ['23', '', '211', '100'], 'pack_count': [23, 10, 1, 1]}

# Create DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["price_per_unit"] = (df["price"].str.replace('', '0' ).astype(float) \
                                / df["pack_count"].astype(float))\
                                    .apply(lambda x: '' if x == 0 else round(x, 2))
                                    
print(df)
```

This is the result I get:

```
   
  price  pack_count price_per_unit
0    23          23          88.26
1                10               
2   211           1         201010
3   100           1         100000
```

I used replace to handle empty strings but something weird is happening as you can see in the output above.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I modify it such that if `price` column is an empty string, then we skip the calculation for that column and assign a default value, otherwise do the required calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `str.replace` method, use `replace` method.

`str.replace` replaces each occurrence of the pattern in the Series, i.e. matches in any part of the strings. So for example, `'23'` is changed to `'02030'`, which becomes `2030.00` when changed to float, which divided by `23` becomes `88.26`.

Meanwhile `replace` replaces values given in `to_replace` with `value`, i.e. looks for exact matches.

```
df["price_per_unit"] = (df["price"].replace('', '0').astype(float)) \
                                / df["pack_count"].astype(float) \
                                    .apply(lambda x: '' if x == 0 else round(x, 2))
```

Output:

```
  price  pack_count  price_per_unit
0    23          23             1.0
1                10             0.0
2   211           1           211.0
3   100           1           100.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does str.replace behave erroneously?

Comment: @hsnsd `str.replace` looks for pattern, `replace` looks for exact match. You want the exact match.